# connection to AWS mysql instance using python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have inserted new records into mysql. How can I insert live sensor data as new records into existing tables in my mysql AWS instance using python script?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please add more context to your question and some code to show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that port (3306) is open on your AWS instance.

And that user has required access on that database.

Here values will be the one that are received from the sensors.

```
import MySQLdb

myDB = MySQLdb.connect(host="AWS_IP.0.0.0",port=3306,user="XXXXX",passwd="XXXXX",db="XXXXX")
cHandler = myDB.cursor()
cHandler.execute("INSERT INTO table_name ( field1, field2,...fieldN ) VALUES ( value1, value2,...valueN ); ")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)